# RESTEasy: Adding a method that can be invoked without authentication

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I have an application which exposes a RESTful API using RESTEasy. The user needs to authenticate using HTTP-Basic before any method can be invoked.

However, I want to add a method to the RESTful API which any user can invoke without authenticating. How do I do that? Is there some JAX-RS/RESTEasy annotation that I can add to the method declaration to indicate that authentication is optional for that method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your web.xml exclude REST paths, that does not need authentication

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/unchecked/*</url-pattern>
     <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
     <http-method>PUT</http-method>
     <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
     <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
     <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
     <http-method>GET</http-method>
     <http-method>POST</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Then your REST resource that does not need authentication should be something like

```
@Path("/unchecked")
public class NoAuthResource{


}
```